# INNER JOIN two tables which were created by UNION ALL in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to merge to tables with UNION ALL command. Then I want to INNER JOIN the results with another table. I played with the following structure but it does not work:

```
 (Select * from TableA
 UNION ALL
 Select * from TableB)
 INNER JOIN TableC
 ON somekey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   select * 
   from   (Select * from TableA union all Select * from TableB) t1
   inner join TableC t2 on t1.somekey=t2.somekey;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) the result of your `UNION ALL` and select from that

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   (SELECT * FROM TableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TableB) ua 
       INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.somekey = ua.SomeKey
```